# Root Nexus 4 Lollipop without PC

Tags: root-access, 5.0-lollipop

Is it possible to root Nexus 4 Lollipop from the phone, without needing to connect to a PC of some sort? Since Lollipop update, Android file transfer cannot find my phone.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site anymore after posting the question, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Framaroot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/root-framaroot-one-click-apk-to-root-t2130276). I'm not sure if it will work with Lollipop, but it is the only option I can think of that does not require a PC. More info and FAQ in the link. Download the latest version from the bottom of the first post.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://kingroot.net, download and install their apk. Then run the app and try to root the phone. This is one of the best rooting app. Tried it with many many devices and it worked well.

Comment: 2 questions: Are you sure kingroot will work on a Nexus? What about the side-effects of it? Seeing how many issues pop up here for one of them, I'm not sure I'd even recommend it as last resort.

Comment: Kingroot doesn't work on any devices. Tried and tested.

Answer (score 0):

You can Root your device with any one of these 2 tools

[KingRoot](http://kingroot.net),

[Kingoroot](http://www.kingoapp.com/)

its recommended to turn on oem unlock from developer settings as it won't block or trigger FRP,

apps which are mentioned above are used for mainly 3 reasons
1. No need for PC.
2. No Bootloops or other major issues like in flashing.
3. They first check for success rate and availability of root strategy for your specific device.

Note:

*NO ONE CAN GUARANTEE WHEN IT COMES TO ROOT WITHOUT PC.

*ANY APPS INSTALLED WHILE ROOTING WITH THESE APPS CAN BE REMOVED AFTER YOUR DEVICE GETS ROOT(u can even debloat system apps).

*ROOTING WITH SUPERSU OR MAGISK HAS HIGHER SUCCESS RATE OF ROOTING BUT U NEED TO FLASH CUSTOM RECOVERY MAY LEAD TO BOOTLOOPS AND BRICKING.

for devices running on lollipop there is a 50% probability of getting root without pc using any of these apps in your device just install Kingroot try to root if it fails then try kingo if that fails too then you need to flash custom recovery then use supersu or magisk zip to get root access

but rooting a device makes warrenty void I personally do not support rooting its purely your will